# jQuery issue with .submit()

Tags: jquery, submit

In the code below, "clicked" is logged out, but "submitted" is never logged. Anyone know why? The IDs are correct.

```
$('#submitModal').click(function(){
    console.log("clicked");
    $('#createEvent').submit(function() {
        console.log('submitted');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What element has ID createEvent? Could you please put your example to http://jsfiddle.net/ for testing?

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin the form has the ID createEvent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code binds a handler. It doesn't trigger one.

```
$('#createEvent').submit(function() {
    console.log('submitted');
    return false;
});
```

You'd need to bind it first, then trigger it when needed.

```
  // bind the click
$('#submitModal').click(function(){
    console.log("clicked");
    $('#createEvent').submit(); // trigger the pre-bound submit handler
});

  // bind the submit
$('#createEvent').submit(function() {
    console.log('submitted');
    return false;
});
```

Also you may have some issues if `$('#submitModal')` is a submit button to a `form` element. Not sure.